# Rails ActionMailer Content-Type" => "text/Calendar' for iCalendar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, icalendar

In a webapps, i'm generating a ics string for sending an invite with mail.

I'm using icalendar gem for generate the ics string but i need to send with the Content-Type : text/Calendar.

How can i set ActionMailer to do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check how to do it in the documentation:

[ActionMailer](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionMailer/Base) In the Default Hash section

like

```
class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base
  def some_message(recipient)
    content-type "your type"
  end
end
```